# Append parameter to url during ajax call with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameters

I need to append a parameter in the url called by a ajax call.

I need something like this:
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(functionThatAppendsParameterToUrl);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/append-parameter-to-url-during-ajax-call-with-jquery

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`ajaxSend`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) rather than `ajaxStart`.  Your function is called with the event, request and settings as parameters.  If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you should be able to modify the settings to include your parameter.

Comment: It seems not to work :( with ajaxSend I can read the settings parameter but I cannot write them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be that you're using `type: "POST"` instead of `type: "GET"`